# 3.5mm headphone jack frequency range

Tags: mobile

I want to receive audio data from a device and handle it through the mobile’s headphone jack, but my data has a low frequency of about **1Hz**. I’ve found that it’s too low for this port.
I’ve searched about the **3.5mm headphone jack** frequency range but couldn’t find anything!
What is your suggestion? **USB** port can be an alternative solution?

Comment: How could anyone know how to help you given what information you have provided. Also, check out the following guidelines regarding questions like this: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic - note the "not about" section.

Comment: We speak English here.  If you can't, get someone that does or don't post here.

Comment: @OlinLathrop ooookkk!!! thanks for your advise Mr. Lathrop. you are very angry!

Comment: It's not the 3.5mm jack which is imposing the lower frequency limit, it's the device its a part of which will have a limited capability in that area. The jack itself will quite happily pass frequencies all the way down to 0Hz (DC).

Comment: @brhans thank you. i think using 3.5mm jack is almost complicated and needs more research. what do you think about using USB? Implementation is easier? supports low frequency?

Comment: @Mojtaba. audio jack is for transmission only, and has no frequency limits. The headphones plugged in it may have response limits, to optimize sound production. In your case, options to receive serial data would be via USB, bluetooth, WiFi, mic, IR receiver, NFC, etc. The mic jack also has no frequency limits, for receiving but audio processor chip may filter frequencies outside audible range. Check your phone spec sheet.

Comment: @Zimba: There may also be some signal conditioning circuity between the jack and the codec chip, that removes DC, protects against ESD, etc.

Comment: @BenVoigt: By "filter frequencies outside audible range" I meant audio chip will process  mic audio to maximise audible range by design. OP wants to receive audio and headphone jack does the opposite.

Comment: @Zimba: And I meant that it is not only the "audio processor CHIP", but the whole circuit, that one needs to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very nearly incoherent.  You do not say (clearly) whether you want to put data into the cell phone and analyse it there, or whether you are going to send data out of the cell phone to be analysed by an external system.

Regardless, certain parts of your question can be answered.

1. The audio range of the earphone of a cell phone can't be counted on to go below 100Hz - some phones will go lower, some will not even get down to 100Hz.
2. The audio range of the microphone of a cell phone can't be counted on to go below 100Hz - some phones will go lower, some will not even get down to 100Hz.
3. The phone itself will not convert from some nebulous, undefined "data" to audio or from audio back to data - your software will have to do that.

To work around the limitations of the cellphone audio, you would be better advised to modulate the data on to an audio frequency that the phone can handle - in the middle of the speech band is probably best, so 1200Hz to 1800Hz.  You can find plenty of data on the internet about frequency shift keying (FSK) or phase shift keying (PSK) for transmitting data across audio systems.

If none of that made sense, then you have a long way to go before you begin working on your data transmission.  Read up on things.  Define your data format and data rate.  See what you can come up with for ways to achieve your goal.  If you get stuck, come back and write a better question - and consider telling us what you are trying to do, as someone here may have done it already and can point you at a better way.